# To be off the ground for a few seconds and then fall on the floor

Tags: verbs, vocabulary, phrases

When somebody hits someone with his shoulder and the other person gets knocked over and his feet are off the ground and because of the momentum and the force, he literally falls a few meters ahead, how would a native speaker express the situation of the other person’s being off the ground?

What I’m looking for is a proper verb or phrase to describe the other person’s feet being off the ground (no touching the ground and moving forward in the air for a second) In my native language we would say “he flew off the ground” but I don’t think in English we can use “to fly” in this context. The phrase should emphasise that he was off the ground in the air for a second before he lands or falls.

Comment: You can say someone was hit so hard they "flew backwards" in English, and you can say someone was "knocked off his feet" (though that wouldn't necessarily emphasise the airtime). "I hit him so hard he was knocked off his feet and flew backwards until he hit the wall."

Comment: As Showsni says, a person can be "knocked off their feet" or, to emphasize the lack of contact with the ground, "knocked clean off their feet." See this news article: https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-8331805/Pedestrian-knocked-clean-feet-exploding-tyre-truck-hit-bollard.html